# React Native: What is the use of SafeAreaProvider

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What is the use of SafeAreaProvider?
I didn't understand the github documentation https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context.
For what i have to use it ? `SafeAreaView`  makes a nice job...
Even if `SafeAreaProvider` must be used with React-navigation:

```
<SafeAreaView>
  <SafeAreaProvider>
    <NavigationContainer>
      ...
    </NavigationContainer>
  </SafeAreaProvider>
</SafeAreaView>
```

I do not see its use...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

safe areas is phone **screen without notches**, Such items include:

1. Physical notches
2. Status bar overlay
3. Home activity indicator on iOS
4. Navigation bar on Android

The area not overlapped by such items is referred to as "safe area".

you can see more example and images in reactnavigation.org [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/handling-safe-area/) and you will understand.

#### with SafeArea the content will be

[image]

#### without SafeArea the content will be

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know the use of SafeAreaView, but what is the use of SafeAreaProvider ?

Comment: it is `react context provider` see https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider, away to pass props down, this will calculated the safe area once and pass it down to all `SafeAreaViews` and` hooks` like `useSafeAreaInsets`

Answer (score 1):

Doing some tests to see if I can avoid using `SafeAreaProvider`, seems like there might be no need for it if you are just using `SafeAreaView` (tested on mobile, not sure on web since the docs say it needs different config.). If however, you want to use any of the inset values via hooks, such as `useSafeAreaInsets`, then you are require to do so.

If you don't know what a provider and a consumer are, then check it out [contexts in react](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Therefore, I don't think safeAreaView consumes from this provider, since it still works fine without it.

It would help if it was clearer, this was just the conclusion of a simple test.